# Adding a sales receipt to Quickbooks Online with .NET using the IPP SDK API

Tags: api, sdk, quickbooks

This probably has a really obvious answer, but I've been stuck searching for it for a few hours now.

I'm trying to figure out how to create the sales receipt using the sdk api, for linking a payment made by a customer to his invoice.  As far as I can tell, if I don't do this, the payment will get deposited to the account but the invoice will never be updated.

I'm able to read invoices, make credit card or echeck payments, and read the customer record.

But I'm trying to create a sales receipt, and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I can read the customer record but how do I add it to the sales receipt?

This just gives me a syntax error:

```
Customer customer = readCustomerUsingEmail(email);

SalesReceipt salesReceipt = new SalesReceipt();
salesReceipt.CustomerRef  = Customer;
```

When I hover over customer, it states "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer' to 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType'".

Edit: Ok. I'm now using the Payment object instead of the SalesReceipt object.

I *think* I've figured out the answer but I haven't run it yet.  It just doesn't show a syntax error.

```
 ReferenceType customerRef = new ReferenceType()
        {
            Value = customerData.Customer.Id,
            name = customerData.Customer.DisplayName
        };
        payment.CustomerRef = customerRef;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to do something very wrong here: `create the sales receipt using the sdk api, for linking a payment made by a customer to his invoice`

That is *not* what a sales receipt does.

**Invoice** - Indicates a customer owes you money.

**Payment** - Indicates a customer paid you money -- this is essentially the "other side" of an invoice. You create an invoice to indicate they owe money, and you create a payment to pay off the invoice.

**Sales Receipt** - Indicates a customer both owed you money *and* already paid. e.g. this is essentially an invoice and a payment combined into one object, for use when both the invoice and payment happened at the same time.

Soooo...

1. A sales receipt *can not link to an invoice*
2. A sales receipt *is not used* to link a payment to an invoice

What you should be doing is just creating a payment, and linking the payment directly to the invoice. To create a payment, you need to supply at minimum:

- The customer (the `CustomerRef` field)
- The total amount (the `TotalAmt` field)
- A `Line` object (for use linking to an invoice)
- The line `Amount` (if it's a payment for a single invoice this generally be equal to the `TotalAmt` field
- A `LinkedTxn` node, which a link to the Invoice to pay (the `TxnId` field)

See the examples of creating a payment and additional docs here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/payment

Example:

```
{
    "CustomerRef":
    {
        "value": "20",
        "name": "Red Rock Diner"
    },
    "TotalAmt": 55.00,
    "Line": [
    {
        "Amount": 55.00,
        "LinkedTxn": [
        {
            "TxnId": "69",
            "TxnType": "Invoice"
        }]
    }]
}
```

There's tons of sample code here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/40_sdks/01_.net/0004_sample_code_and_sample_apps

And one specific to `Payment`s here:

- https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-CRUD-.Net/blob/master/SampleApp_CRUD_.Net/SampleApp_CRUD_.Net/Entities/TransactionEntities/Payment.cs

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks.  Ok, that helps because I wasn't sure which to create.  But the question still remains:  How do I add the CustomerRef to the payment object using the .net object?  I can create it using Payment payment = new Payment(); but then how do I add the customerref part?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look at Intuit's sample code? (Added a link to it in my post). Does the autocomplete functionality in Visual Studio not work for you?

Comment: Am I overthinking this?  If a customer makes a credit card transaction online, should I be including the invoice number in the transaction to have it automatically link to it?  Or do I still need to call the api to create a payment record?

Comment: Hi Keith.  I've been looking at Intuit's sample code for months now.  The link in your code doesn't actually describe how to add data to the objects.  It only describes what to add.  The c# syntax isn't included.  The autocomplete functionality in VS works fine but one still has to know how to add things.  For example, it's not all that obvious that to add a customerref, you need to use ReferenceType, not when the return type of Customer (when selecting customers) is not ReferenceType.

Comment: C# code is certainly there - https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-CRUD-.Net/blob/master/SampleApp_CRUD_.Net/SampleApp_CRUD_.Net/Entities/TransactionEntities/Payment.cs     How is something like this not obvious that you need a `ReferenceType`?  `p1.CustomerRef = new ReferenceType() { Value = "1" };`

Comment: Thanks Keith, I see it there now.  I must have missed the link earlier.